# Repeating players turn if spot is already taken in tic tac toe game

Tags: java

I have to create a program of tick tac toe for an assignment I am doing.

I have run into an issue where the program will skip the players turn if the spot in the array has already been chosen.

I was wondering if anyone would know how to help me fix this...

for example: I enter in the array[1][1] and the second player chooses that position as well. The program will not update the board and continue on to the next player therefore skipping their turn.

I will paste my code below and if anyone has any questions don't hesitate to ask.

```
public class TicTacToe {

public static char[][] board = new char[3][3];
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
public static String keepPlaying;
public static char yesOrNo;
public static boolean playing;
public static int row, col;
public static User human1 = new User();
public static User human2 = new User();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    human1.getUser1Name();
    human2.getUser2Name();

    System.out.println("\nPlayer 1: " + human1.human1Name() + ": X's");
    System.out.println("Player 2: " + human2.human2Name() + ": O's\n");

    initializeBoard();
    displayBoard();

    playing = true;


    while (playing == true)
    {

        System.out.println("\n" + human1.human1Name() + " it's your turn.");
        human1.getChoice();
        human1.convert();


        if (human1.returnRow() == 0 && human1.returnCol() == 0/* && board[0][0] == ' '*/)
        {
            board[0][0] = 'X';
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if (human1.returnRow() == 0 && human1.returnCol() == 1 && board[1][0] == ' ')
        {
            board[1][0] = 'X';
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if (human1.returnRow() == 0 && human1.returnCol() == 2 && board[2][0] == ' ')
        {
            board[2][0] = 'X';
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if (human1.returnRow() == 1 && human1.returnCol() == 0 && board[0][1] == ' ')
        {
            board[0][1] = 'X';
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if (human1.returnRow() == 1 && human1.returnCol() == 1 && board[1][1] == ' ')
        {
            board[1][1] = 'X';
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if (human1.returnRow() == 1 && human1.returnCol() == 2 && board[2][1] == ' ')
        {
            board[2][1] = 'X';
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if (human1.returnRow() == 2 && human1.returnCol() == 0 && board[0][2] == ' ')
        {
            board[0][2] = 'X';
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if (human1.returnRow() == 2 && human1.returnCol() == 1 && board[1][2] == ' ')
        {
            board[1][2] = 'X';
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if (human1.returnRow() == 2 && human1.returnCol() == 2 && board[2][2] == ' ')
        {
            board[2][2] = 'X';
            displayBoard();
        }

        if (checkForWinner() == true)
        {
            System.out.println("\n" + human1.human1Name() + " has won the game!!!");
            playAgain();
            if (playing == false)
            {
                break;
            }

        }

        if (board[0][0] != ' ' && board[0][1] != ' ' && board[0][2] != ' ' && board[1][0] != ' ' && board[1][1] != ' '
                && board[1][2] != ' ' && board[2][0] != ' ' && board[2][1] != ' ' && board[2][2] != ' ')
        {
            System.out.println("It's a draw!!!");
            playAgain();
            if (playing == false)
            {
                break;
            }
        }



        System.out.println("\n" + human2.human2Name() + " it's your turn.");
        human2.getChoice();
        human2.convert();

        if (human2.returnRow() == 0 && human2.returnCol() == 0 /*&& board[0][0] == ' '*/)
        {
            board[0][0] = 'O';
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if (human2.returnRow() == 0 && human2.returnCol() == 1 && board[1][0] == ' ')
        {
            board[1][0] = 'O';
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if (human2.returnRow() == 0 && human2.returnCol() == 2 && board[2][0] == ' ')
        {
            board[2][0] = 'O';
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if (human2.returnRow() == 1 && human2.returnCol() == 0 && board[0][1] == ' ')
        {
            board[0][1] = 'O';
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if (human2.returnRow() == 1 && human2.returnCol() == 1 && board[1][1] == ' ')
        {
            board[1][1] = 'O';
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if (human2.returnRow() == 1 && human2.returnCol() == 2 && board[2][1] == ' ')
        {
            board[2][1] = 'O';
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if (human2.returnRow() == 2 && human2.returnCol() == 0 && board[0][2] == ' ')
        {
            board[0][2] = 'O';
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if (human2.returnRow() == 2 && human2.returnCol() == 1 && board[1][2] == ' ')
        {
            board[1][2] = 'O';
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if (human2.returnRow() == 2 && human2.returnCol() == 2 && board[2][2] == ' ')
        {
            board[2][2] = 'O';
            displayBoard();
        }


        if (checkForWinner() == true)
        {
            System.out.println("\n" + human2.human2Name() + " has won the game!!!");
            playAgain();
        }

        if (board[0][0] != ' ' && board[0][1] != ' ' && board[0][2] != ' ' && board[1][0] != ' ' && board[1][1] != ' '
                && board[1][2] != ' ' && board[2][0] != ' ' && board[2][1] != ' ' && board[2][2] != ' ')
        {
            System.out.println("It's a draw!!!");
            playAgain();
        }


    }


}

public TicTacToe() {

    board = new char[3][3];

}

public static void initializeBoard() {

    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
            {
                board[row][col] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }

public static void displayBoard() {

    System.out.println("    A   B   C");
    System.out.println("  -------------");

    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        System.out.print((row + 1) + " | ");
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        {
            System.out.print(board[row][col] + " | ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("  -------------");
    }
}

public static boolean checkForWinner() {

    if (board[0][0] == board[0][1] && board[0][1] == board[0][2] && board[0][1] != ' ')
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (board[1][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[1][2] && board[1][1] != ' ')
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (board[2][0] == board[2][1] && board[2][1] == board[2][2] && board[2][1] != ' ')
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (board[0][0] == board[1][0] && board[1][0] == board[2][0] && board[1][0] != ' ')
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (board[0][1] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][1] && board[1][1] != ' ')
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (board[0][2] == board[1][2] && board[1][2] == board[2][2] && board[1][2] != ' ')
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board [1][1] == board[2][2] && board[1][1] != ' ')
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (board[0][2] == board [1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0] && board[1][1] != ' ')
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public static boolean playAgain() {

    System.out.println("\nWould you like to play again?");

        keepPlaying = scan.nextLine();

        yesOrNo = keepPlaying.toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    if (yesOrNo == 'N')
    {
        System.out.println("\nThanks for playing!");
        playing = false;
        initializeBoard();
        return playing;
    }   
        else if (yesOrNo == 'Y')
        {   
            initializeBoard();
            displayBoard();
            return true;
        }
    return playing;
}

public static boolean notValid() {

    if (human1.returnRow() > 2 || human1.returnRow() < 0 || human1.returnCol() > 2 || human1.returnCol() < 0 || human2.returnRow() > 2 
            || human2.returnRow() < 0 || human2.returnCol() > 2 || human2.returnCol() < 0 || !isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean isEmpty() {

    if (board[0][0] == ' ' && board[0][1] == ' ' && board[0][2] == ' ' && board[1][0] == ' ' && board[1][1] == ' '
                && board[1][2] == ' ' && board[2][0] == ' ' && board[2][1] == ' ' && board[2][2] == ' ')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("That position is taken.\n");
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Your programming is skipping the turn because it is doing exactly what you told it to do.

```
else if (human2.returnRow() == 1 && human2.returnCol() == 1 && board[1][1]==' ')
    {
        board[1][1] = 'O';
        displayBoard();
    }
```

If the spot picked is [1][1] AND it is not occupied then update. If the spot is already occupied, then the code inside the if statement will not be executed and the program will continue.

An alternative method of checking and accounting for the spot being taken without messing with your existing code too much could be

```
boolean turnOver = false;
while(!turnOver){
    if(board[human2.returnRow()][human2.returnCol()] != ' '){
    System.out.println("That space is taken")
    }else{
    if(human2.returnRow() == 1 && human2.returnCol() == 1){
      board[1][1] = 'O';
      displayBoard();
     }

   //other cases
   turnOver = true;
   }
```

Additionally, your code is quite redundant. Your goal of updating the board and checking if that position is filled could be achieved with a single method call instead of the 10 if statements.

```
public void setPosition(int row, int col, int player){
  if(board[row][col] != ' '){
      System.out.println("That space is taken")
      return;
  }

  if(player == 1){
    board[row][col] = 'X';
  }else{
    board[row][col] = 'O';
  }
}
```

Comment: when I try this it only accounts for the one user though

Comment: could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I have a human1 object and a human2 object that I need for the requirements of the assignment and when I tried to use the method setPosition, it only accounts for the first object. Therefore, any choice player 1 enters will have no effect.

Comment: My mistake, I edited the method so it should work as intended.

Comment: im still having issues with it... say I keep my code how it is because it sets all the position in the correct spots and I can check for a winner properly. how could I change it so that it will repeat the player turn if that spot is filled? because right now I have it so that the board will not be altered if that spot is already taken.